# Headers lost in chained fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm currently trying to chain API requests to retrieve user information with React Native. The problem that I am running into is that the first fetch request goes provides the response that I'm looking for, but the chained request hangs up.

I've been able to narrow this down by running the API on my machine and here's what the problem is. When the first request is made, the headers in the config object are passed through without issue. When the second request is made, the `X-Tenant-Name` header is passed through, but for some reason the `Authorization` header is lost in the process, and therefore the request fails.

Here's the function making the requests:

```js
  async componentWillMount() {
    const { authToken, selectedUser, tenant } = this.props;

    const config = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-Tenant-Name': tenant,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
      }
    }

    await fetch(URL + '/users/' +  selectedUser.id, config)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ user: response.data });
      const children = response.data.relationships.following_tips.data;

      if (children.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          fetch(URL + '/tips/' + children[i].id, config)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => console.log(response))
          .done();
        }
      }
    })
    .done();
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that your are not passing config to the second one.

Comment: That's my bad on the copy-paste front. The error occurs even when the config object is passed in

Comment: check my answer, if it works, please vote it up and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is being caused because your are forgetting to pass `config` to the second `fetch`. Try this one:

```js
async componentWillMount() {
  const { authToken, selectedUser, tenant } = this.props;

  const config = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-Tenant-Name': tenant,
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
    }
  }

  await fetch(URL + '/users/' +  selectedUser.id, config)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ user: response.data });
    const children = response.data.relationships.following_tips.data;

    if (children.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        fetch(URL + '/tips/' + children[i].id, config) //Add config to this fetch too.
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .done();
      }
    }
  })
  .done();
}
```

Comment: That was my mistake when I was copying the function over from my editor. The error occurs when the config object is passed

Comment: Ok, are you sure that your service is responding at that endpoint? I mean, how does `URL + '/tips/' + children[i].id` look like? I suspect that you're not receiving data, so you are never getting into the second fetch...

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am getting a response from the server and I have the API running locally so I am able to see the incoming headers. `X-Tenant-Name` is in both responses, but `Authorization` is only in the first. Because the API uses JWT for auth, all I get back is `{ error: 'You need to sign up or sign in before continuing' }`. Somewhere the header is being lost. I have also made sure that I can receive data at that endpoint w/ postman

Comment: did you try copy/paste your config into the second one? Maybe there is a context losing. I'm going to make a small lab to see if i can reproduce it as well.

Comment: I did. I also logged the variables inside of the context of the `.then()` call and the config object is still in scope